# Canonical Java answer for object reference assignment "why does x change when I mutate y after x = y"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I have noticed a large number of Java questions that are really just variants of:

"*When I update `b`, `a` changes - please help.*"

```
SomeObject a = new SomeObject("myObject");    
SomeObject b = a;
b.setName("myBackup");
System.out.println(a.getName()); // prints myBackup but it should say myObject ?????????
```

For example a two-second search pulls out 3 from the last 24 hours alone:

- [Why it is wrong to copy a list in java by " = "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707972/why-it-is-wrong-to-copy-a-list-in-java-by)
- [how to create two copy of same ArrayList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684232/how-to-create-two-copy-of-same-arraylist-in-java)
- [Java - LinkedList is initialized incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695503/java-linkedlist-is-initialized-incorrectly)

I acknowledge that this is a hard question to search for before you ask it, but I would have thought a canonical answer for "close as duplicate" would still be a good idea. So:

1. Does anyone know of a (surely [older than this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011724/java-object-assignment)) canonical answer to the question "*Why doesn't assigning one object to another create a new object*"?
2. Should all these questions be closed as duplicates of such a canonical question, or should we keep on collecting all the variants of this question without closing them? <sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup> *I ask this as many are about copying lists, some are worded specifically about cloning lists, and some aren't about collections at all*

Comment: [One of the first ones I've found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java), and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072727/duplicating-objects-in-java)

Comment: Any good "explain pointers" question would suffice.

Comment: @Deduplicator - what's an "explain pointer"?

Comment: Any good question about explaining pointers would suffice. <== Rephrased for you.

Comment: @Deduplicator [Judging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7480783/4639281) [from](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2629357/4639281) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2500555/4639281) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16504084/4639281) I'd say a well explained canonical would be useful.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen - yes, it would have to be Java specific

Comment: I think the answers to the question [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) address that question as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my worry with using that question is that the answers focus on arguments to methods. Passing arguments to methods works in the same way as assigning to variables and fields, you say? Yes, *I* know that. But people asking these questions might not know it, and the top answers to that question don't seem to explicitly address it. (I agree that they address the same concepts and are recommended reading for people with these sorts of questions.)

Comment: @DanGetz I've been wanting for a very long time to write/answer a canonical question for "What is the difference between a value, a reference, a variable, and an object?". I've put it off because it might be too broad, but you could use it for all these topics.

Comment: Maybe we could even have a language-agnostic canonical reference (for all languages with "call by sharing" semantics?

Comment: The same happens in the python tag too (and probably many other languages).

Comment: @Bergi That can be confusing. C++ `auto& x=y;` or `void f(some_object& x)` is not the same as Java `SomeObject x=y;` or Python `x=y`.